# Require sourceforge-appscript error only with plist

Tags: ruby, plist, require, sourceforge-appscript

As an exercise to learn Ruby, I wrote a script that requires appscript.
I created a plist in /Library/LaunchAgents to execute the script when my Mac starts.

The problem is, if I run the script from the terminal it works flawlessly, but when it is executed from the plist I get this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- appscript (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/LeoMB/Ruby/Apps/DesktopChanger/DesktopChanger.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I've already tried: `gem update --system`  but that didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Apps have a different PATH than shell. Did you check to see that they match? See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63662/how-to-change-path-environment-variable-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-that-will-be?lq=1 for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've found interesting information on LSEnvironment to include different PATH in the plist. It still does not work though. What I don't understand is why I get no error for the other gems required, if the problem is in the PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've restarted the system and reinstalled rb-appscript and this solved the problem.
I don't know what was going on, but the question can be closed.